# Ansible Parse for value from REST API Response Header

Tags: ansible, http-headers

I must be missing something obvious. I need to extract the value from one key in the response header of a GET API call.

I am trying to get the value of **client_version** but cant seem to pull that data out.

Anisble version: 2.4.2.0

**playbook:**

```
- name: Get test client version
  uri:
    url: "{{ current_client_version_url }}"
    method: GET
    header:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
  register: resp

- debug: msg={{ resp }}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "msg": {
        "content_length": "180",
        "status": 200,
        "cookies": {},
        "x_ratelimit_reset": "1",
        "json": {
            "defaultContainerAlias": "_default",
            "exchangeContainerAlias": null,
            "hasContainersEnabled": true,
            "hasExchangeEnabled": false,
            "hasTargetedOffers": false,
            "autoDeleteItemReferences": false
        },
        "url": "https://some.url.goes.here.com/v1/subdir/metadata",
        "changed": false,
        "vary": "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent",
        "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "3",
        "failed": false,
        "connection": "close",
        "content_type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "client_version": "1a2b3c4d5f",
        "date": "Tue, 04 Aug 2020 22:34:34 GMT",
        "redirected": false,
        "x_ratelimit_remaining": "197",
        "msg": "OK (180 bytes)"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

I assumed it would be a regular Ansible output and have tried:

resp.msg.client_version

resp.msg['client_version']

resp.msg[client_version]

When I reference **resp.msg** in the debug statement, I just get:

```
"msg": "OK (180 bytes)"
```

which makes no sense to me...

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out solution is **resp.client_version**. it made sense funny enough once I pasted here. there is another key **msg**.